# JQuery Append with list items and keep URL

Tags: jquery, url, menu, popup, append

I'm trying to create a small list search so that when something is typed in, the list pops up. I'm using jquery to trim the list as matches are found but I can't figure out how to keep the URL in place.

Could someone point out how to change the "append" part in order to keep the list intact with all relevant information?

Code is as follows

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script> 

    <style>
        ul.drop a { display:block; color: #fff;}
        ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px   solid #fff; background: #555; color: #fff;}
        ul.drop { position: relative; }
        ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #1e7c9a; }
        ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; background: #555; border: 1px solid #fff; }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(function() {
                var opts = $('#menu li').map(function(){
                    return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
                });

                $('#menu').click(function() {
                    var txt = $(this).text();
                    alert(txt);
                });

                $('#someinput').keyup(function(){
                    var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput').val(), 'i');
                    var optlist = $('#menu').empty();
                    opts.each(function(){
                      if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                          optlist.append($('<li>').text(this[1]));
                  }
                    });

                });

            });

        });//]]>  

    </script> 
</head>
<body>

    <input id="someinput" onkeydown="document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'visible';" onblur="document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'hidden';">

    <ul id="nav" class="drop">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="#" onclick=">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Instead of removing and appending the list items, why not just hide and show them?

Comment: Any solution would be great. The problem is I literally just started using jquery 20 minutes ago so I really don't know how to do anything with it yet. I got some code for making a list shrink with searching, I then cut it till I had roughly what I was looking for lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $('#someinput').keyup(function(){
                var rxp = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $("#menu li").each(function(){
                  // .toggle() will show or hide the element depending on the argument
                  $(this).toggle(rxp.test($(this).text()));
                });
            });
```